# Drupal multiple variables in block content

Tags: php, variables, drupal, block

I am trying to print out multiple variables in a block content, but drupal returns:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$search_field' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\seu\xampp\htdocs\iptp\sites\all\modules\custom\lasearch\lasearch.module on line 70
```

Here is my Code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view
 * 
 * This creates a block which shows the search results
 * 
 * @param type $delta
 * @return type
 */
function lala_search_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();

    switch ($delta) {
        case 'lala_SEARCH_RESULT':

            $block['content'] = array(
                '#markup' => _lala_search_search_page(),
            );
            return $block;
            break;
    }
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'lala_lanavigator':
        $search_field = module_invoke('search', 'block_view', 'search');
        $search_text = _lala_search_get_laavigator('prefix');
            $block['title'] = t('la-Navigator');
            $block['content'] = $search_text $search_field['content'];
            return $block;
            break;
    }
}
```

I am new to PHP and I am britty sure that the problem depends on my syntax :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php
    $block['content']  = $search_text
    $block['content'] .= drupal_render($search_field['content']);
?>
```

This way drupal wil render the array for you.

Here is more info about it: https://drupal.org/node/26502

Comment: Altough that works, i must say it is not best practice. You should look in the search module what theme() function they use and process your content array with that. That way you will be able to preprocess it in your theme if needed. But that might come in a later stage in your drupal career ;)

Answer (score 1):

For:

`$block['content'] = $search_text $search_field['content'];`

Perhaps you meant:

`$block['content'] = $search_text . $search_field['content'];`

Comment: when i am trying this, drupal doesnt return me any error, but the output just gives me
helloArray, hello is actually the value of the search_text variables

Comment: That is because the second variable `$search_field['content']` is an array.  I'm not familiar with that hook's return, I'll look into that real quick.  But the original issue you ran into is that in order to assign two variables to a single one, you have to specify an operator of some sort or run them through a function.

Comment: Oh, yup, `drupal_render($search_field['content'])` as in the other answer.  His breaks out the concatenation into two statements. In mine with one line, it would be `$block['content'] = $search_text . drupal_render($search_field['content']);`